# Android SQLite "on UPDATE cascade" not working

Tags: android, sqlite

Android SQLite ON UPDATE CASCADE not working
Please help me
These are my tables

```
    String tablausuariocreate="CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS USUARIO(" +
            "idusuario INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
            "DELETED BOOLEAN DEFAULT(0))";

   String tablazonacreate="CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS ZONA(" +
        "IDZ INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
        "NAME VARCHAR(150)," +
        "idusuario integer," +
        "DELETED BOOLEAN DEFAULT(0)," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(idusuario) REFERENCES USUARIO(idusuario) on update cascade)";

 String tablaclientecreate = "CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS CLIENTE(" +
        "IDC INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
        "NAME VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE," +
        "IDZ INTEGER," +
        "idusuario integer," +
        "DELETED BOOLEAN DEFAULT(0)," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(IDZ) REFERENCES ZONA(IDZ) on delete set null on update cascade," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(idusuario) REFERENCES USUARIO(idusuario) on update cascade )";
```

Comment: Can you show us your error log?

Comment: when I update  zone does not update cliente

Answer (score 1):

In this line you have set the foreign key to set null on deletes, rather than cascade:

```
"FOREIGN KEY(IDZ) REFERENCES ZONA(IDZ) on delete set null on update cascade,"
```

You should set it to `on delete cascade`.
You might also need to recreate the tables for changes to apply (remove the `IF NOT EXISTS` condition).